# Instanciar Objeto dinamicamente

Tags: java, reflexão, webhook

Bom dia, estou precisando instanciar uma classe de acordo com o parametro recebido por um *webhook*, alguem tem alguma idéia de como fazer?

Seria mais ou menos isso (alguns cenarios):

#### Cliente

1. Recebo JSON `{"id":"1"}`
2. Devo criar uma referencia a classe `ClienteDao` quem implementa uma interface coletor com um metodo coleta.
3. Meu Objeto integracao recebe o objeto coletor (`ClienteDao`) e chama o metodo coleta, que consulta o banco e faz o parser para JSON.
4. Objeto integracao devolve o JSON para o *webhook*.

#### Produto

1. Recebo JSON `{"id":"2"}`
2. Devo criar uma referencia a classe `ProdutoDao` quem implementa uma interface coletor com um metodo coleta.
3. Meu Objeto integracao recebe o objeto coletor (`ProdutoDao`) e chama o metodo coleta, que consulta o banco e faz o parser para JSON.
4. Objeto integracao devolve o JSON para o *webhook*.

#### Carrinho

1. Recebo JSON `{"id":"3"}`
2. Devo criar uma referencia a classe `CarrinhoDao` quem implementa uma interface coletor com um metodo coleta.
3. Meu Objeto integracao recebe o objeto coletor (`CarrinhoDao`) e chama o metodo coleta, que consulta o banco e faz o parser para JSON.
4. Objeto integracao devolve o JSON para o *webhook*.

Soluções excluidas:

1. Serie de comandos `if` -> procedural
2. Tabela com id e classe, onde eu salvo o id do *webhook* e o .class a instanciar. Fazendo uso de *reflection* instancio a classe -> soa como gambiarra.

Estou buscando uma solução elegante e que no futuro não terei dor de cabeça para manter.

Comment: Acho que uma pergunta válida é por que você quer fazer isso? Não seria melhor ter uma URL de *callback* diferente para cada tipo de recurso?

Comment: Obrigado @AnthonyAccioly ! Então, estou integrando com uma ferramenta de rastreio  de pedidos. A plataforma utiliza de um webhook para tratar todas as requisições, desta forma eu tenho que filtrar na minha ponta. Só posso fornecer a eles uma porta de entrada e baseado no envio deles eu trato do meu lado e envio a resposta.

Comment: Ok, nesse caso acho que cabe compartilhar mais detalhes e um exemplo de código... A forma trivial de fazer esse tipo de dispatching seria usar um mapa ID -> Objeto Integracao com o dao correto. Outra opção seria fazer [Lookup programatico](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup) anotando os Daos com anotações `@MyWebhook(forId="x")` ou ainda [métodos produtores](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producer_methods.html) tudo depende da sua arquitetura e framework.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly é isso mesmo que estou querendo fazer com lookup programatico!!! Estou usando Spring Boot, ainda nao implementei nada... os exemplos acima são apenas estudo de caso para explicar o que eu precisava. Voce pode me explicar melhor como fazer com Lookup programatico?

Comment: Oi Thiago, existem varias maneiras de fazer isso no Spring... Desde lookup por nome do bean no *Application Context*, passando por *factories*, *service locators*, *qualifiers*, *autowired* em um mapa, etc, etc, etc. A solução ideal vai depender da arquitetura da sua aplicação e do gosto do freques. Sugiro que você amadureça a idéia, implemente algo e, ao chegar no ponto de ter ao menos um [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edite sua questão com o código, fica mais fácil discutir esse tipo de coisa em cima de um exemplo concreto.